# Make div slide a little from the right

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a div with text inside to slide into it's position (into it's place that I specified in my css) from the right when the page loads, but not from the end of the page, but only from a 20 or 30 pixels.

I tried a couple of options, but cannot seem to hit the nail with this. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Please share some code with us, we'll appreciate your effort ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by initially adding a margin to your div. Then you can add a class that changes this margin back down to zero on page load:

**CSS**

```
#div{
 margin-left:30px;
}

.after-load{
 margin-left:0px;
 transition-duration:.5s // you can change this as you need.
}
```

Then on page load add the 'after-load' class to this div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#div').addClass('after-load');
});
```

Comment: Think it would be better to use css transforms and avoid jumps on page.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some default styles and add a class with jquery on page load..
and add some styles with this added class.. you can use transition to make the effect smooth...

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $('.my-div').addClass('active-class');
});
.my-div {
    transition: right 0.25s ease;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}
.my-div.active-class {
     right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [JQuery Animate](http://jsfiddle.net/d7m4q4n1/2/)?

**HTML:**

```
<img id="book" src="http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/browsers-mail/145092d1379294855t-multiple-web-pages-1-screen-page-untitled.png" alt="" width="100" height="123"
  style="position: relative; right: 0px;">
  <br><br><br>
<button type="button" id="clickme">
  Click here
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
    alert("Image will animate 50px to the right side");
    $( "#book" ).animate({
      left: "+=50",
      right: "0"
    }, 5000, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d7m4q4n1/2/